# c++ Passing unique_ptr as a reference to another function

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

This seens to be basic, but I need some help.

I have a sample class:

```
class myClass {
   int a;
   int b;

}
```

Then a factory:

```
class myFactory {
    std::unique_ptr<myClass> getInstance()
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<myClass>(new myClass);
    }
}
```

Then I have several funtions that will receive `myClass` by reference:

```
doSomething (myClass& instance)
{
    instance.a = 1;
    instance.b = 2;
}
```

And the `main` code, where  I´m stuck:

```
main()
{
    myFactory factory;
    std::unique_ptr<myClass> instance = factory.getInstance();

    doSomething(instance.get()) <--- This is not compiling
}
```

How do I correctly call the `doSomething()` function passing the instance as a reference as expected ?

Note that `doSomething()` will modify instance data...

Comment: get() returns a pointer, your function takes a reference.

Comment: `operator*` to access the pointee, just like your plain old raw pointer.

Comment: you might be interested in [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) (as an alternative to your factory eg.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr<T>::get` returns the underlying raw pointer, not the pointee. `unique_ptr` provides `operator*` for directly getting at the instance.

```
doSomething(*instance);
```